# Add a condition with alias value

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to add an additional condition

```
SELECT
   ROUND(SUM((cus.amount_product/1000)),1) as TOTAL_N,
   ROUND(SUM((cus.amount_product/1000)),1) as TOTAL_PRODUCT
FROM customs AS cus
LEFT JOIN customs_products AS cp ON cp.id = cus.customs_product_id
   WHERE cp.product IN (101,103,104,106)
   AND TOTAL_PRODUCT  >= 1
```

The problem is in this `TOTAL_PRODUCT`. I tried to do that in multiple ways :

```
1. AND (ROUND(SUM((cus.amount_product/1000)),1)) > 1 --> NOT WORKING
2. AND TOTAL_PRODUCT  >= 1 --> NOT WORKING
```

Can you help me please ? What I'm doing worng

Comment: Do `HAVING TOTAL_PRODUCT  >= 1`. (MySQL specific trick.)

Comment: To get true `LEFT JOIN` result, move `cp.product IN (101,103,104,106)`condition to the `ON` clause.

Comment: Your query just doesn't make sense.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: "Do HAVING TOTAL_PRODUCT >= 1. (MySQL specific trick.) " i believe it's not only MySQL  specific trick @jarlh .. i believe the SQL standard actually allowes the use of `HAVING` clause without `GROUP BY` clause  when i see this BNF `<table expression> ::= <from clause> [ <where clause> ] [ <group by clause> ] [ <having clause> ]`

Comment: @RaymondNijland, the syntax is fine, but the column alias is not in scope in the HAVING clause. You need a derived table (sub-qeury) or similar.

Comment: "the syntax is fine, but the column alias is not in scope in the HAVING clause. You need a derived table (sub-qeury) or similar. " @jarlh i know.. Also i didn't say that replacing WHERE with HAVING without GROUP BY was wrong syntax.. I said that it seams to be allowed by SQL standard so it might not be only a MySQL specific trick and might work in other databases systems as well that was mine comment about.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, The ANSI SQL syntax allows a HAVING clause without a GROUP BY clause. But ANSI SQL does not allow that column alias in the HAVING clause - **semantically**. _That_ is a MySQL specific trick.

Comment: right @jarlh that i have to agree on you need to use `HAVING ROUND(SUM((cus.amount_product/1000)),1)` instead off `HAVING TOTAL_PRODUCT` which MySQL allowes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `HAVING` clause does what you want, but your query just doesn't make sense.  You have the same expression twice.  Even if that is a typo, the `WHERE` clause is turning the `LEFT JOIN` into an inner join.  I suspect you may really want:

```
SELECT COUNT(cus.customs_product_id) as TOTAL_N,
       ROUND(SUM((cus.amount_product/1000)), 1) as TOTAL_PRODUCT
FROM customs_products cp LEFT JOIN
     customs cus
     ON cp.id = cus.customs_product_id
WHERE cp.product IN (101, 103, 104, 106)
HAVING TOTAL_PRODUCT >= 1;
```

I suspect that you might actually want a `GROUP BY` in the query as well.

Answer (score 0):

USE `having` as it use aggregated function it will not work in `where clause`

```
SELECT
   ROUND(SUM((cus.amount_product/1000)),1) as TOTAL_N,
   ROUND(SUM((cus.amount_product/1000)),1) as TOTAL_PRODUCT
FROM customs AS cus
LEFT JOIN customs_products AS cp ON cp.id = cus.customs_product_id
   WHERE cp.product IN (101,103,104,106)
having ROUND(SUM((cus.amount_product/1000)),1)>= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

use having which is group filter

```
SELECT
   ROUND(SUM((cus.amount_product/1000)),1) as TOTAL_N,
   ROUND(SUM((cus.amount_product/1000)),1) as TOTAL_PRODUCT
FROM customs AS cus
LEFT JOIN customs_products AS cp ON cp.id = cus.customs_product_id
   WHERE cp.product IN (101,103,104,106)
  having TOTAL_PRODUCT  >= 1
```

as `TOTAL_PRODUCT` is alias of the aggregated column so you need having